# SQL Query Accross Three Tables Requiring Different Joins

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. An Applications (relevant field is AppID) table containing information about various application available to download, a Packages table (relevant field is PackageID) containg information on the various downloadable items available and an App/Packages table (relevant field is AppID and PackageID) which shows which packages should be downloaded for each application. I need a query to find out which packages are not related to a specific application.

My idea was to INNER JOIN Applications to AppPackages to get a list of all the packages that are related to an Application and then OUTER JOIN this resultant set to Packages and find all the null results to show which packages were not related.

The problem is I can't seem to work out how to chain these queries. Subqueries don't seem to work, and EXIST/NOT EXIST requires information from the outer query which I just can't make work. I'm assuming there's something simple I'm mising, but all the literature I read is for two tables, never more than two.

This is my best attempt, but the EXISTS part doesn't work for the reason mentioned above.

```
SELECT Packages.PackageID FROM Packages WHERE NOT EXISTS
(Select AppPackages.PackageID, AppPackages.AppID FROM AppPackages WHERE AppPackages.AppID = @AppID)
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Cheers,

Matt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a query to find out which packages are not related to a specific application.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Packages p
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM Applications a 
           INNER JOIN AppPackages ap ON ap.PackageId = p.PackageId
     WHERE ap.AppId = <Your App ID>
  )
```

Comment: this does the job perfectly (well seems to so far with limited testing), many thanks! I've never seen SELECT 1 before..I shall have to find out how this works.

Comment: @Matty W: `SELECT 1` is just an alternative form of `SELECT *`. It's a little more explicit way of saying that you don't *actually* want any column returned.

Comment: Ok so i've tried to use the output of this query in my asp.net website, however it appears that the columns name for each of the 4 columns is the same...PackageID. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @Matty: The column names are whatever the SQL Server gives you for this query. Namely, it should be all columns from `Package`, since the query is a `SELECT *`.

Comment: I agree...If I run a test query as part of configuring the data soure, the column names come back PackagID, Description, AppLocation, Enabled. If I bind to a colunm other than PackageID, the aspx page can't find it and if I parse out all the column names using code, they're all PackageID

Comment: Quick update, my parsing code was wrong....all the correct column names are there...now to work out why I can't bind them to a control.

Answer (score 0):

I would try sth like this:

```
SELECT Packages.PackageID FROM Packages WHERE Packages.PackageID NOT IN
(Select AppPackages.PackageID FROM AppPackages WHERE AppPackages.AppID = @AppID)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've been asked to aboid using IN in queries as apparently it's a far more intensive operation. As such and because Tomalak's answer works, I haven't tried using this.